# Away3D Camera undefined properties

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, away3d

I am trying to get the examples from the Away3d tutorials working.

view = new View3D();

```
var cont:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
cont.addChild(view);
addElement(cont);

//setup the camera
view.camera.z = -600;
view.camera.y = 0;
view.camera.lookAt(new Vector3D());
```

I can instantiate the View3d object with no problems, but Flash Builder complains that the  z, y, and lookAt properties of view.camera are undefined.  If I do auto complete on view.camera I can see other properties and methods of the camera, but not z, y, or lookAt().

The API reference for Away3D 4.1 Camera3D class does not list lookAt() as a method anymore, so it looks like it has been removed.  So I guess the tutorials on the Away3D site are outdated.  Does anyone know of more up to date documentation, or the new way of accomplishing the equivalent of the code sample?
I cant go any further through the tutorials until I figure this out.

I am using Away3d 4.1.1 Beta as an external swc linked to my project, a Flex 4.6 web project in Flash Builder 4.6.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Camera3D inheritance chain is Entity > ObjectContainer3D > Object3D. Most of the properties and methods you list are either defined in Object3D or overridden in ObjectContainer3D (like lookAt) therefore they should still be accessible.

Maybe try creating a Flex Library project with the Away3D code and link it in your project?